# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'rbcart.product' doesn't exist

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am creating an application where whenever I click on product tab it should list all the product from database. So below are the files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-bean">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rbcart"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.emusicstore</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

So when I click on product tab it is giving me error
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'rbcart.product' doesn't exist

[image: Error Page]

But hibernate should create table itself.so what is wrong in this?

Comment: Can you include your `Product` entity mapping by chance?  Do you see the table in that database if you query the database directly?

Comment: No there is no table in database.Hibernate should create the database right? And I am doing this using annotation.So there is no need for xml mappig right? and In product class I have given @Entity for Class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My problem was that I had the id saved as a String (in the model class) and I added the annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO). If I commented the annotation, the table was created in the database and the error didn't appear anymore. 
Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you didn't create the schema. you can try modify the url by adding "?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true" like this: